# Local installation of python 3.5 doesn't find its libraries

Tags: python, linux

After building and installing Python 3.5.1 into `$HOME/.local`, the installed version can't seem to find its own libraries that were installed in `$HOME/.local/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload`.

The python3.5 executable will show the following:

```
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python 3.5.1 (default, Jan 26 2016, 15:40:42) 
[GCC 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/pythonstart", line 7, in <module>
    import readline
ImportError: No module named 'readline'
```

If I set `PYTHONHOME=$HOME/.local` as recommended, the first two lines will disappear, but it will still fail to import `readline` (and `math` and most other modules).

If I actually start python while inside `$HOME/.local/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload`, it will succeed in loading the libraries. So I'm guessing that the import path isn't set correctly.

Is the `PYTHONHOME=$HOME/.local` recommendation wrong? Or is there another env variable that needs to be set to let it find the libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload` fixed the problem, but I strongly suspect that's a shoddy workaround and it should find that folder automatically in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you simply need to add Python's shared libraries to system-wide dynamically linked libraries, something like that:

```
echo "/usr/local/python35/lib/" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python35.conf
echo "/wherever/your/.so/files/used/by/python35/live/" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python35.conf
```

Then on commandline: `ldconfig -v`.

Incidentally, you should not have dynamic libraries in your `$HOME/.dir` directory. This should be system wide as Python runtime is typically understood as system-wide program. Why did you `configure` Python compilation to `$HOME/.local`? Typical `prefix` should be something like `/usr/local/python35` (for "local" installation).

The only "normal" situation for having Python installation to a subdirectory of your `$HOME` is where you do not have access to root account on the system *and* the sysadmin for some reason refuses to compile Python for you, but you *really* have to have it in this particular version.

If you're on Debian/Ubuntu, typically you do not even have to compile latest Python or other new software yourself, there are "backport" repos for this.

**UPDATE**

Since it seems you cannot add it system-wide indeed, the only reasonable option I see is like this:

1. add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to your `.bash_profile` like so:

   `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/python35/libs:/other/libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

   `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

This ensures your `.so` files are seen by dynamic linker (`ld`), but that's visible in your login shell only.

2. add your Python's installation `bin` dir in `PATH` in `.bash_profile` in a similar way:

   `PATH=/your/python35/bin:$PATH`

   `export PATH`

This puts your Python 3.5 first in `PATH` so you have it found first (I guess that's what you could want). It also allows you to use shebang "mantra" for your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If you use this, you can run it on your account and elsewhere (e.g. in some virtualenv, on system Python 3.5 elsewhere, etc) without modification.

Comment: Well, if I had that access, I wouldn't be installing to `~/.local` ;)
I do need a particular version of Python (as well as headers) and because that version isn't available in the opensuse version we're on, the sysadmin would also have to compile it manually. It's just too much of a hassle - and the non-privileged install also keeps it from messing with other users.